# awk array parsing with two possible location of fields

Tags: arrays, awk, field

I want to use awk to parse through a text file which has fields separated by commas. I need to find out the number of times each state occurs in the file and find the state with most frequent occurrence. I also need to find out if a last name occurs more than once. 
The second field in the file corresponds with the last name but field 5 or 6 can have the state names. Also the first line of the text is used to store the names of the fields so that should be skipped. Here is a portion of the data file:

```
First Name,Last Name,Address,City,State,Zip
Rose,Stark,9283 Vivamus Avenue,Toledo,OH,13856
Remedios,Barber,Ap #331-7101 Elit, St.,Rock Springs,WY,88149
```

In second line the state occurs in the 5th field whereas in the third row it occurs the 6th field. Here is my code:
...

```
BEGIN { FS=","
}

{states1 [$5] += 1}

{states2 [$6] += 1}

{names [$2] += 1}

END {

    for (state in states1)
        print state, states1 [state]
    print "-----"

    for (state in states2)
        print state, states2 [state]
    print "-----"

    for (name in names)
        print name, names [name]

}
```

...

How can I filter out the results other than state names in 5th and 6th fields and how can I print the state with highest occurrence and last name that occurs more than once?

The sample output that I want to get is something like this:

"State with most frequent occurrence is VA. It occurs 8 times.
Last name "Brown" occurs more than once. It occurs 3 times."

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: When you say `field 5 or 6 can have the state names` do you mean a) within a single file the state abbreviation `WY` could appear under the `State` column or under the `Zip` column or b) in some files `State` is the 5th field while in other files `State` is the 6th field, or c) something else?  In the cases where the state appears in the 6th field, what appears in the 5th - the zip or something else? Whatever it is include that in your sample input/output since it's very important. Are your `State`s always 2-letter abbreviations?

Comment: Within the same file the state names occur on 5th field with some occurring in 6th field. In case the state appears in the 6th field, some misplaced characters appear in the 5th field like "Rock Springs" in the third line of example. If that occurs all the fields after that misplaced text are shifted by one. This is only in a handful of the lines but enough to mess-up the output.  The state names are always two capital letters.

Comment: So when the 6th field is 2 upper case letters can we assume THAT is the state name and ignore the contents of the 5th field? Again, please update your sample input to show at least one of these rainy-day cases ad add the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: Wait - you're saying that that "Rock Springs" case is such an example? So the issue isn't that there's anything wrong with your State or Zip columns it's that your Address column can contain commas? Can any other columns also contain commas or just that Address one? Are the fields in your real data enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: I see you added an attempt at expected output but it's crucial when asking a question that the expected output you provide is **the output you expect from the input you provide**, not the output you'd expect from some different input that you didn't show us. Anything else requires more effort than necessary for those of us trying to help you to understand and doesn't give us some input/output that we can simply test a potential solution against. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Yes, we can assume that the two adjacent capital letters are state names. Also, you are right. We can say that the problem is that one additional comma sometimes appears in the address field, and we can assume only in address field. The post updated to show a sample output.

Comment: It shows **A** sample output but not **THE** expected output given the input you provided. Come up with a good, consistent sample input/output so it's easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us your expected output yet so idk what that'd look like but here's enough to get you going: Given what you shared in the comments under your question, to create arrays of states and associated last names along with how many there are would be this using GNU awk:

```
awk -F, '
NR>1 { states_names[$(NF-1)][$2] }
END {
    for (state in states_names) {
        for (name in states_names[state]) {
            print state, length(states_names[state]), name
        }
    }
}' file
```

Note the use of `$(NF-1)` instead of `$5` so I don't care about any commas in preceding fields, the state is in the 2nd-last field, that's all.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Now I have all the states with their occurrence and all the names with their occurrence.  How can I print only the ones with highest occurrence?

Comment: See [@Cyrus's first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600053/awk-array-parsing-with-two-possible-location-of-fields/61602003?noredirect=1#comment108964667_61600053) (and others I've made) for how best to get help. See also [ask] if that's not clear.